# Help with index - linear algebra system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the set of solutions of $A^{(i)}x^{(i)}=b^{(i)}$ where $i \in {1,2}$ where

$$A^{(1)}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\5&1&4\\4&-1&0\\3&4&5\end{bmatrix}, b^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},
A^{(2)}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&4\\-1&1&4\\4&-1&0\\3&4&5\end{bmatrix},
b^{(2)}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

No, I don't really understand what this means,,,should I simply compute $A^{(1)}x^{(1)}=b^{(1)}$ and $A^{(2)}x^{(2)}=b^{(2)}$? And the two solutions of x would be the set of the solutions which the question asks for?

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do. First do it for $i=1$, and then for $i=2$. Note that $A^{(1)}$ and $A^{(2)}$ only differ in the second row.

Comment: i just did it this way and realised that $A^{(2)}*x^{(2)}=b^{(2)}$ has no solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 4 equations with 3 unknowns, which means that it's unlikely that these systems have solution. But it's still possible they do - so it can be 1 or infinite or 0 solutions. So "finding a set of the solutions" means:

1. Find 1 particular solution if the system has it
2. Show that the system doesn't have solutions. This is going to happen if during Gaussian elimination you get some_non_zero_value = 0. Or vice versa.
3. Or represent *all* of the infinite solutions with some expression.

In the last scenario you should get with linearly dependant columns, so:

1. You'll end up with one particular solution - some vector $x^{(i)}_p$.
2. Then once you calculated Null Space you'll get a vector that results in $A^{(i)}x^{(i)}_n = 0$. Any multiple of this vector ($\alpha x^{(i)}_n$) will still result in $0$.
3. Therefore the set of all solutions will be: $x^{(i)}_p + \alpha x^{(i)}_n$. Because $A(x^{(i)}_p + \alpha x^{(i)}_n) = b^{(i)}$.

Comment: Ehmmmmmm do i need the nullspace for this question? Can't i just simply compute the two equations and x1 and x2?

Comment: i just realised its a 4*3 matrix and i cant use inverse for the calculation....ehmmm

Comment: I computed both and the first $A^{(2)}∗x^{(2)}=b^{(2)}$ and the first one actually has one solution only

Comment: @JerryCohen, that's probably the purpose of the exercise - to show that _sometimes_ 4x3 matrices will have 1 solution and in other cases they'll have infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @JerryCohen, sorry, I actually meant that in most cases 4x3 will have 0 solutions (though they may have 1 or infinite too). Will rewrite the answer %)